# Flutter appbar leading back to previous page error:Null check operator on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar

i want to go back to my previous page, first i tried `Navigator.pop(context);` but it returns a black screen. Second try was with this code which i use it to another screen works fine there but here it return this error: Null check operator on a null value

Second try was with this code which i use it to another screen works fine there but here it return this error: Null check operator on a null value

```
Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  ShowSessionsPage(widget.appController)),
                );
```

full code:

```
import 'ShowSessionsPage.dart';
import 'event.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/datepicker.dart';
import '../../Panels/SessionOrBookingPanel.dart';
import '../../Controllers/AppController.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Calendar extends StatelessWidget {
  late AppController appController;
  Calendar(appController){
    this.appController = appController;
  }  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Calendar',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(appController),
    );
  }

}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  late AppController appController;
  MyHomePage(appController){
    this.appController = appController;
  }

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  late final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateRangePickerController _datePickerController = DateRangePickerController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.appController.list);
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              color: widget.appController.themeController.appBlackDeepColor,
              tooltip: 'Back',
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              icon: (widget.appController.deviceIsAndroid) ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_back) : const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  ShowSessionsPage(widget.appController)),
            );
              },
            ),
          ),
          body: SfDateRangePicker(
            view: DateRangePickerView.month,
            monthViewSettings: DateRangePickerMonthViewSettings(firstDayOfWeek: 6,
            specialDates:widget.appController.specialDates),
            monthCellStyle: DateRangePickerMonthCellStyle(
              specialDatesDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  border: Border.all(color: const Color(0xFF2B732F), width: 1),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle),
              blackoutDateTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),
              specialDatesTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiple,
            onSelectionChanged: _onSelectionChanged,
            controller: _datePickerController,
            onCancel: () {
              _datePickerController.selectedRanges = null;
            },
          ),
        );
  }

 void _onSelectionChanged(
     DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs dateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs) {
   print(dateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs.value);
 }
}
```

Error console:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building ShowSessionsPage(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#0c696]], state: _ShowSessionsPageState#fbc3f):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ShowSessionsPage ShowSessionsPage:file:///C:/Users/birbi/Desktop/electromobility_flutter_application/lib/Account/Sessions/Calendar.dart:72:63
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _ShowSessionsPageState.build (package:electromobility_flutter_application/Account/Sessions/ShowSessionsPage.dart:60:49)
#1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#5      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2659:19)
#6      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#7      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#8      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#9      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#10     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#14     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#15     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#16     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================
```

showSessions code:

```
class ShowSessionsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  late final AppController appController;

  ShowSessionsPage(appController) {
    this.appController = appController;
  }

  _ShowSessionsPageState createState() => _ShowSessionsPageState();
}

class _ShowSessionsPageState extends State<ShowSessionsPage>{
  List<SessionOrBookingPanel> sessionPanels = [];
  bool sessionsLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadSessions();
  }

  void loadSessions() async {
    if (await widget.appController.fetchChargeTransactions())
      setState(() {
        sessionsLoaded = true;
      });
  }

  void createSessionPanels(List<dynamic> sessions) {
    int i = 0;
    sessionPanels.clear();
    if (sessions.length != 0){
      while (i < sessions.length){
        sessionPanels.add(new SessionOrBookingPanel(sessions[i], widget.appController, true, true));
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    createSessionPanels(widget.appController.sessions);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        leading: IconButton(
          color: widget.appController.themeController.appBlackDeepColor,
          tooltip: 'Back',
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          icon: (widget.appController.deviceIsAndroid) ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_back) : const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.sessions,
          style: TextStyle(color: widget.appController.themeController.appBlackDeepColor),),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: sessionsLoaded ?
      Column(
        children: [ ElevatedButton(child: Text('Open Callendar'),
            onPressed: () => {Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new Calendar(widget.appController)),
            )}),
          Expanded(
            flex: 15,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
              child: ListView.separated(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index) => sessionPanels[index],
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(color: Colors.transparent,),
                  itemCount: sessionPanels.length),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
          :
      Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: edit your question with full code

Comment: add error log from your console.

Comment: The error is in `ShowSessionsPage` but the code is missing. Please include it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `MaterialApp`. The error happens because of the null operator (`!`) in `Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.sessions,`. Because there is no `AppLocalizations` in the context it throws an error as it returns `null`.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
  supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
  ...
```